# I don’t know what smart thermostat to use with my high voltage

Tags: wiring, thermostat, smart

[image]I think I have 120v but not 100% sure, I don’t know what the wires do. I live in a condo with water cooling/heating furnace. Can someone help explain what the wiring means. Because I do not have a neutral wire so it makes it a little harder. I would be okay with adding a neutral but I have no idea how.

Comment: You haven't actually told us anything about the wiring you have, other than that there isn't a neutral.  Your question is also more appropriate for https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to hire someone with the right knowledge, I mean: an electrician. There is no shame in not knowing this and/or not being able to figure this out. It **is** a shame if you do this yourself anyway and shock yourself and/or damage the equipment. Working with electricity requires knowledge. So be safe and hire an electrician!

Comment: It appears that you have neither the equipment nor the experience to do anything with that thermostat. That disqualifies the question for answers here and indicates that it is pretty risky to do anything with only assistance from an internet forum. The thermostat does not appear to be a type that can be replaced by the kinds of smart thermostat that are widely available. It is entirely possible that only an exact replacement can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

The question here is:
Can someone help explain what the wiring means?

This looks like a Barber-Colman TC-115. I couldn't find any circuit diagrams for it, but simple thermostats like what I think you have typically work like switches. When heat is needed, it shorts two wires together (heat and common). When cooling is needed, it shorts the other one with the common (cool and common). You'd need the circuit diagram and to test it, but it's possible red is heat, blue is cool, and yellow is common (again, you must check this with a multimeter and/or circuit diagram to confirm!)

Also, thermostats can take your main AC voltage, or they can take a stepped down voltage (24V AC, for example), or they could use DC for signaling.

EDIT: this is for informational use only about what the wires do. If you aren't experienced with this or have the right tools, it is dangerous. As far as I know, high voltage AC thermostats require special smart thermostats. I think the most common big box store ones can't handle it.

Comment: So will any smart thermostats work with my set up that you know of?

Comment: I just edited it. I don't know, the DIY boards might knows more. I have an old house with a similar thermostat, and when I tried to get a Nest about 8 years ago, it wouldn't work. I think the "professional" version of the Nest might work, but I haven't looked into it in a while. I just got a programmable thermostat from Lux and have been using that instead.

Comment: In my case to run a smart thermostat that accepts 120v would I need to run a neutral wire from the furnace?

Comment: @gabe you would have to check the circuit diagram to see if yellow is connected to neutral or not. There are also those two wire nuts in the junction box - if they don't go anywhere, they may be neutral too. If any of those are neutral, you can use that. There may be no "hot" in that junction box, however. One of those wires nuts may be hot too. To do it right, check what your boiler uses for control (voltages and wires), and then match whatever your smart thermostat needs.

Comment: Okay thanks you very much

Answer (score -4):

You are probably seeing the 3 phases of the 3-phase AC. Generally if you have a 3-phase load you don't need a neutral but if you decide to cut 2 of the wires to provide voltage to a 1-phase load you will need a neutral.

***DO NOT*** try to cut some of the wires without protection equipment and better hire an electrician

Comment: A condominium with 3-phase power? No, I don't think so.

Comment: If it isnt connected to neutral do you have a better explanation?

Comment: I added a picture of what I have behind my original thermostat, I was looking at the mysa thermostat but I just wanna know if would work with mine, and if not what do I need to do?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson My mom's condo had 3-phase power. Granted, that wasn't in the US, and I agree it's  uncommon, but apparently not impossible :)

Comment: Do you know what she did?

Comment: I would assume that the three wires are single phase line in, line out for heat, and line out for cooling. Conventional mechanical thermostats do not need a neutral.